# Two Instances of Symfony2 on the same server not behaving properly

Tags: php, apache, symfony, doctrine

I currently have two instances of Symfony2 running on a vanilla Ubuntu server.

Instance 1:
/var/www/site

Instance 2:
/var/www/test-site

Both instances have their own independent VHost configurations with DocumentRoots pointing to the above folders.

Both instances have their own independent parameters.yml files configured to create different databases through a Doctrine configuration.

Issue:
When running /var/www/test-site/php app/console doctrine:database:create (Instance 2), the command errors out saying that "database for site (Instance 1) already exists".

Expected:
The command should successfully create the database named and configured for Instance 2.

More Info:
All of the configuration files are relative or absolutely bound to %kernel_dir%. Doing an echo of the configuration path generated by AppKernel.php shows that the correct path is being chosen.

One user on #symfony had mentioned something about Apache environment variables but I'm not sure where to find that information.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache before running the command?

Comment: Found the issue and it was one of those boneheaded tired developer problems. Closing this question. Situation normal.

Comment: Was it because you were using `/var/www/test-site/php app/console doctrine:database:create` rather than `php /var/www/test-site/app/console doctrine:database:create`

Comment: It was a literal value inside config.yml rather than a reference to the parameters.yml file. Just a boneheaded mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to code when you're exhausted from a severe sinus infection.